# Setting a Different axis for child and parent objects

Tags: mesh, parent

[image: Default Axis for Parent]

I have several meshes I have set up with primitive rigging, however one of them is designed to slide at an angle. When I set the angled meshes Axis correctly it also changes the parents Axis, which makes the other rigging not work as intended.

Is there a way to have each on a different axis without changing the others?

[image: Modified axis. The parent now also has this axis]

Comment: U mean other than global, normal local and gimbal, view u need other transform orientation is that so

Comment: @atek I've only been using Blender about a week, so correct me if I'm wrong: Global axis is the one you can see on the 'background'. Local is the one associated with that mesh; above it is rotated about 30 degrees from the global. I want the Don't Panic portion to slide out, but the only way I've found to do that correctly (Ctrl-space) also causes the other meshes axis' to change, which messes up their transforms